# Populating HashMap in object from request with BeanUtilsBean

Tags: java, http, request, javabeans, populate

My current application populates a simple java object from a http request using this kind of function:

```
// request is an instance of org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
// myObject is an instance of MyBusinessDTO
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate( myObject, request.getParameterMap( ) );
```

It works well for almost any use case, but I'm still stuck with one, fill HashMap from my request parameters.

The object I want to fill looks like:

```
public class MyBusinessDTO extends BusinessDTO
{

    private Map<String, Object> listeFormsChecked = new HashMap<String, Object>( );


    /**
     * @return the listeFormsChecked
     */
    public Map<String, Object> getListeFormsChecked( )
    {
        return listeFormsChecked;
    }



    /**
     * @param listeFormsChecked the listeFormsChecked to set
     */
    public void setListeFormsChecked( Map<String, Object> listeFormsChecked )
    {
        this.listeFormsChecked = listeFormsChecked;
    }
}
```

I've tried my request such as:

- prefixPath.myBusinessDTOAttribute.key=value
- prefixPath.myBusinessDTOAttribute[key]=value

But none of them work.

Is this even possible ? And if yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, and am just getting my feet wet with beanutils too, but from the javadocs it sounds like your idea isn't supported:

> "This method uses Java reflection APIs to identify corresponding
>   "property setter" method names, and deals with setter arguments of
>   type String, boolean, int, long, float, and double. In addition,
>   **array** setters for these types (or the corresponding primitive types) can also be identified."

So, arrays, but no maps.

But you could try to work with two synchronized (not in the java sense) arrays, and set those both independently in separate variables with beanutils -- iow your keys would be one array with its own getter and setter, and the vals would be a second array with its own getter and setter, and then you could have a utility method in the bean that automatically merges them into a map.